# Exception using client and trying to add vertices

Tags: .net-6.0, gremlin, tinkerpop, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

Steps in the code:
1.Declared Azure Cosmos DB Configuration variables(Host , PrimaryKey , Database ,Container)
2.Connection Pool
3.WebSocketConfiguration
4.GremlinServer

After all above steps, when I was using gremlin client and trying to add vertices getting below exception:
using (var gremlinClient = new GremlinClient(
gremlinServer,
connectionPoolSettings: connectionPoolSettings,
webSocketConfiguration: webSocketConfiguration))
{

```
          var g = Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(gremlinClient));
            var v1 = g.AddV("person").Property("name", "marko");
            var v2 = g.AddV("person").Property("name", "stephen");
            **g.AddV("Person").AddE("self").To(g.V(1));**
```

}

EXCEPTION :
System.ArgumentException: 'The child traversal of Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.Bytecode was not spawned anonymously - use the __ class rather than a TraversalSource to construct the child traversal'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `to(g.V(1))` just use `to(V(1))` or `to(__.V(1))` .

The use of a `g` mid traversal was deprecated in the 3.5.x line of Apache TinkerPop and removed as part of the 3.6.0 launch.

Comment: Thanks for your response
we are using gremlin.net library(with .net core 6) , Where g is reference (obj)

 var g = Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(gremlinClient));

Also I am getting closed connection at server side , Below is the separate post, Could you please share your valuable inputs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682384/gremlin-net-driver-exceptions-connectionclosedexception

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I will take a look. Did my answer resolve the issue described in this question? If, yes, I would appreciate it if you accept the answer. That way others that find the question will know it has an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts  @Kelvin Lawrence.
Actually g is reference in .Net so if I don't use reference of g , it will throw compile time error.

Comment: You should not need to use `g` inside a `V` using the Gremlin .Net client